# Set exact location on a Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I am trying to set exact location on a Facebook Page I administrate. The address is located in the mountains and there is no address in a city near it. I tried several addresses but nothing seems to work. I read that it may take some time for Facebook to update the address so it makes it even harder to get it work. Can someone tell me if I can enter coordinates in the form? Can I drop a pin in a map to set it? Is there any other solution?

[image: facebook page address form]

Answer (score 1):

The other solution is to go there with your mobile, and file new location using GPS. And optionally put few photos to speed up location application consideration.

Comment: Should i check in? Login as an admin and go to this form? How exactly? Please explain more! Did you already did it before?

Comment: I had similar problem in the past few years ago. My friend had opened tiny hotel in my home country, but the company which made him all web-related stuff had hard time to bind hotel FB page to physical address. So what we made - we came to place with my smartphone (with gps), I caused checkin and and filed new location. Since it was FB app and it had live GPS stream, and there were photos, FB approved it in less than 24 hours. Then it was few-clicks effort to bind page to address.

Comment: my pleasure. be prepared to have gsm/3g coverage at the place if that's remote - that was major challenge for us. We solved it with additional 3g/wifi bridge pulled up the tree so it had direct sight to network base station.

Answer (score 1):

Since this post has gone up Facebook has now made it possible to drag and drop the pointer on the map to the exact location you want it in if you are doing it on a PC.

Comment: Oh?  I can't seem to do this.